# How to make a file that handles exported functions for an NPM package?

Tags: javascript, function, npm

I am trying to make a file that checks all JS files and the functions they exported, and then exports those functions out, for an NPM package. Sort of like this.

```
function example(example) {
console.log(example)
}
```

And then there is another JS file that takes this out and exports it.

```
Code that exports all the files in the folder here.
```

Basically so it takes the function, then exports it by its name so when you install the package, and then you call it in your index.js file. You can use the functions like this.

```
const example = require('examplepackage')

example.example('Example')
```

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know how to do it, so please give me a step by step process.